# Session variables between plugins in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am using a plugin which uses oauth to login with provider. I then take the authentication token and store it in a session variable, like:

```
session[:google_auth_token] = token
```

The problem is, when i try to use that variable in *another* plugin, the variable is nil.

I am not getting `CookieOverflow`, and I have confirmed that the variable is set immediately after it is set in the first controller.

Have any ideas to why this is happening? Is there a better way to store the token, like in a hidden `CustomField` in Redmine maybe (seems like overkill)?